# Edit message when new user created

Tags: 7

In configuration>Account settings page, at the bottom of page under E-mails first option `Welcome(new user created by administrator)`, here I want to edit the body section and need to include link for my custom page `/unsubscribe`. I have gone through the available tokens but I did not fine any clue

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `[site:url]`. Alternatively, there is also `[site:url-brief]`